# What is the available version of following in rails smtp.UseDefaultCredentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp

I have following configuration in java file. I m trying to convert to equivalent configuration in RAILS[image]

How do I convert it RAILS configuration for SMTP

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Rails for the `SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials` feature. If I understand [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) correctly, this property makes the SMTP client send the username and password of the **user currently logged into the system**. This is only applicable when NTLM, negotiate or Kerberos-based authentication is used in the system (as documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx)) and all of this is .NET and Windows-related only. Windows server keeps the credentials of the currently logged in users in a credentials cache and can provide them e.g. when sending email.

There is nothing similar available in the Rails environment. Usually, a Rails application has its own single credentials for sending mails, configured in the settings (see the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration) for more info).

If you indeed need separate credentials per each user logged in into the application, you would have to keep the credentials somewhere (e.g. a database) in a way that would allow you to get the cleartext password when sending the email. This of course *has many security consequences*, is generally hard to accomplish securely and thus is not the preferred way (you'd probably have to encrypt the credentials somehow with a per-user key, but I don't know for sure of a best way).

Comment: Looks like u r right @BoraMa. There seems no equivalent for `UseDefaultCredentials` feature. However it seems, It is by default its true. So when there is no authentication it sends those for verification. Let me give my converted code.

Comment: pls check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on @BoraMa answer, By default If we dont give any authentication related keys, Then the logged in user details are sent by Default similar to function

`SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials`

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'xx.xxx.x.xxx',
port:                 25,
ssl:                  false,
enable_starttls_auto: false  }
```

Above configuration worked for me and I was able send emails.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that you are correct that this is equivalent to using `UseDefaultCredentials = true`. Your config sends *no* username / passwords whereas the config from the question sends the credentials of the currently logged-in user (in a .NET environment).